# Where to use pass statement in python?How can i use pass statement efficiently?

Tags: python

I am unable to understand the use of the `pass` statement in Python.

I have found some sample code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm) in which there is a `pass` statement but I am unable to figure out what it is useful for in this context:

```
for letter in 'Python': 
    if letter == 'h':
        pass
        print 'This is pass block'
    print 'Current Letter :', letter
```

Comment: Where did this sample code come from? I think you should avoid that source.

Comment: Also, read the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

Comment: @TimPietzcker i found this code at -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm

Comment: Thanks - that's a wonderful example of how a tutorial should *not* be done. They are explaining that "the pass statement in Python is used when a statement is required syntactically but you do not want any command or code to execute.", and then they proceed to give an example where the pass statement is *not* required syntactically because you *do* want code to execute...

Comment: @TimPietzcker i am a beginner in python so i started learning python from the above mentioned tutorial, i found the above code in that tutorial. so for clarification i asked this question. Can you please suggest me some good tutorial that is really helpful for beginners.

Comment: ...I've just looked at a couple other pages in the tutorial. They are chock full of errors, inelegancies, often fail to make the point (for example *why* one would use a tuple instead of a list) etc. - choose a better tutorial (like the official [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)).

Comment: And by the way, I think those downvotes are unwarranted. You were rightly confused by this tutorial, and you asked a very sensible question. I have edited your question to reflect this, which should allow the downvoters to retract their votes, if they choose to do so.

Comment: i had asked a bad question for that i paid the price.(4 down votes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *pass* is a NOP in Python.  It has no effect on efficiency.  It is merely used as a syntactic placeholder to mark an empty block.

You can use the [*dis* module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#module-dis) to see that there is no difference in the generated code when using the [pass-statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement):

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f(x):
    return x

>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, again but with a pass-statement added:

```
>>> def f(x):
    pass
    return x

>>> dis(f)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that the generated code is no different with the pass-statement.

Hope that helps.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `pass` statement is an empty statement. It does absolutely nothing. The way you have used it, it makes no difference whatsoever.

`pass` is mainly used as a placeholder statement. Suppose you have a function which you plan to implement later. Well, you can't just leave it blank cause that's improper syntax. So, you use `pass`.

```
def spam():
    pass # i'll implement this later
```

A similar use would be in empty loops.

```
for i in xrange(10):
    pass # just add some delay maybe?
```

Answer (score 1):

When we have nothing to do in loop area, and then run the program we get an error. to eliminate this error we can use pass statement.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2oPw.png)

```
for i in range(5):  # when we execute this code we find error.


for i in range(5):  # no error
    pass
```